# how to set multiple ImageViews in a row in Constraint Layout?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to recreate this Layout with ImageViews instead of buttons.

This is what I had so far when using buttons:

[image]

The buttons were all in a row and with equal distance to each other.

Thats the old xml code btw (only the buttons):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOneXXX"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="Back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnTwoXXX"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2XXX" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTwoXXX"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Home"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnThreeXXX"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnOneXXX"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2XXX" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnThreeXXX"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Like"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnFourXXX"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnTwoXXX"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2XXX" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFourXXX"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btnThreeXXX"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2XXX" />
```

I tried to recreate this using ImageViews. This is how it looks so far:

[image]

I kept the xml code nearly the same, as I only changed the view element.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/emptyheart" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/next" />
```

As you can see, the buttons positions are messed up and not in equal distance. I am new to using ConstraintLayout. Can anyone help me on that and explain to me why my code doesn't work as expected and how to solve it? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: check your margin values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, those margins were messing up the positions. I simply get rid of the margins in every ImageView and now they are aligned perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a chain style. In your case, a horizontal one like: `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"` to the first image. You can find more info on this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

You can also add a `layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle`
and give it a value of `packed` or `spread` or `spread_inside`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Issue content]

It's a very simple mistake.
You have added some unnecessary margins.

> Remove those margins and add/remove equal margins for each image.
>   And you can make this as a horizontal chain too(not mandatory)

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
```